java.lang.RuntimeException: Error inflating WebView on Android 8
I'm encountering a crash in my Android application when attempting to inflate a WebView in a fragment. My device is HUAWEI Y6 Prime 2018 .Here's the stack trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4690)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4623)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4575)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2006)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:107)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:731)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:799)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1409)
        at ir.mservices.mybook.databinding.FragmentWebviewBinding.inflate(FragmentWebviewBinding.java:121)
        at ir.mservices.mybook.databinding.FragmentWebviewBinding.inflate(FragmentWebviewBinding.java:107)
        at ir.mservices.mybook.fragments.WebViewFragment.onCreateView(WebViewFragment.java:144)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchPause(FragmentManager.java:2970)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchPause(FragmentController.java:296)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPause(FragmentActivity.java:284)
        at ir.mservices.mybook.core.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:580)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7542)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1420)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4672)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4623)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4575)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2006)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
    Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:231)
        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4552)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4684)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
        ...
 

It seems to be related to the WebView implementation. Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any ideas on how to resolve it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you getting this issue due to your XML layout file. try to change WebView.
otherwise i think you don't initialized objects step by step.
